# The relation between Forward declaration and destructors

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have  the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class CForward;

void func(CForward* frw) { delete frw; }

class CForward
{
public:
    ~CForward() { cout << "Forward" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    func(new CForward);
    cin.get();
}
```

I ran the program, and it printed nothing.

Why?

in main, I created `new CFoward`, and in `func` I deleted it and called it destructor.

It seems that the destructor have not been called. Why? Is  that related anyhow to the forward decleration?

Comment: `g++` actually tells you what's happening when you compile this code.

Comment: At least bump up the warning level on your compiler.  This should always emit a "deletion of pointer to incomplete type" diagnostic.

Comment: GCC is quite helpful: `warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator: [enabled by default] ‘frw’ has incomplete type [enabled by default] forward declaration of ‘class CForward’ [enabled by default] note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Indeed, your forward declaration introduces an incomplete type that is later defined with a non-trivial destructor, and that can't be used in a delete expression:

From n3337, paragraph 5.3.5/5:

> 5 If the object being deleted has incomplete class type at the point of deletion and the complete class has a
>   non-trivial destructor or a deallocation function, the behavior is undeﬁned.

Comment: @user1798362: If you defined your class destructor(rather than just using the compiler generated one), it is non-trivial.  Recursively, if your class has any members with non-trivial destructors, your class has a non-trivial destructor. All other destructors are trivial (they don't actually do anything).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact in the function func, the compiler doesn't know the complete type of cForward. So  the desctructor is neved called.

If you put the function after the class, it will work fine.